# Topological vector spaces with a non-absorbing neighborhood of 0

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Is there any Topological vector spaces with a non-absorbing neighborhood of $0$? If there is one, then when I require the TVS to be Hausdorff, is there still one example?

Answer (score 4):

No. If $x \in X$ and $U$ is any open set containing $0$ then $\frac 1 n x \to 0$ by continuity of scalar multiplication. Hence $\frac 1 n x \in U$ and $x \in nU$ for  some $n$ proving that $U$ is absorbing.